# import python package when module is same name

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I have a module `blah.time` where I do some sanity checks and wrapper functions around normal time and date operations:

```
import time

def sleep(n):
    time.sleep(n)
```

When I call `sleep`, it just throws a maximum recursion error. I'm guessing the namespace is wrong, so I tried using `import time as _time`, but I still get the same error.

How do I reference the system `time` module from within my own module in order to prevent this namespace conflict?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `from __future__ import absolute_import` as the first line in your file.

This will force all imports to be absolute rather then relative. So `import time` will import the standard module, to import a local module you'd use `from . import foobar`

Answer (score 3):

I would read http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports and then use `from __future__ import absolute_import`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your `time` module is shadowing the system `time` module.  The easiest way around the problem is to rename your module to something besides `time`.