# Python import class from different project with same name

Tags: python, import

`Project 1             Project 2
 |-lib                 |-lib
 |  |-Toolkit.py       |  |-Toolkit.py
 |  |-Something.py     |  |-Class.py
 |  |-...              |  |-...
 |-...                 |-...`

Class.py from Project 2 imports Toolkit.py from Project 2 and Something.py from Project 1. Something.py from Project 1 imports Toolkit.py from Project 1.

I can't change Project 1, and would like to keep the name Toolkit.py in project 2. In Class.py, I tried both
`from Toolkit import function1, function2` and `import lib.Toolkit as TK`, but I still have the error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'someFunction'`, which is a function from `Something.py`. How should I solve this?

Comment: Are `Project 1` and `lib` packages (have an `__init__.py`). I'm guessing they are not, but it makes a difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [import python package when module is same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734744/import-python-package-when-module-is-same-name)

Comment: They're separate python projects, without __init__.py

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your projects are packages. (Put a `__init__.py` file in the folders)

Just rename the import and then use it.

```
import Project1.lib.Toolkit as TK1
import Project2.lib.Toolkit as TK2

TK1.do_function()
TK2.do_function()
```

Comment: which folders? Project 1 or Project 1/lib?

Answer (score 1):

```
Import Project1.lib.Toolkit as T1
Import Project2.lib.Toolkit as T2
```

I'm pretty sure this would work, can't say i've tried it though

Comment: You are assuming that Project 1 and lib are packages. Most likely they are not.

Answer (score 0):

These projects have not been designed properly. They should be implemented as packages so that they can have like-named modules without clashing. Think of a name for your project 2 package and then change it to be

```
Project 2
    lib
        mypackage
            __init__.py
            Toolkit.py
            Class.py
```

Then you can use package relative import to get the module you want.